# submitting textbox values with knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to submit the value from a textbox into an array which will be displayed in a table format. Further calculations will be made but right now I'm having trouble with the bindings. In the console in chrome the error I'm getting is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'item' of object#<ItemEntry> is not a function
```

I can't figure out where I'm supposed to define newItem (the value which is submitted from the textbox).

Here's the HTML

```
<td><input type="text" data-bind="value: newItem" /></td>
<button data-bind="click: addItem">Add Item</button>

<table>
    <thead><tr>
        <th>Item Number</th><th>Price</th><th></th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: itemNumbers">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: item"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: price"></td>
            <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeItem">Remove</a></td>
        </tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>

<h3 data-bind="visible: totalCost() > 0">
    Total Cost: $<span data-bind="text: totalCost().toFixed(2)"></span>
</h3>
```

And here's the javascript

```
function ItemEntry(item, price) {
    var self = this;
    self.item = item;
    self.price = price;

}

// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
function EntryViewModel(newItem) {
    var self = this;
    self.newItem = newItem;


    // Editable data
    self.itemNumbers = ko.observableArray([
        new ItemEntry("New Item", "$22.50")
    ]);

    // Computed data
    self.totalCost = ko.computed(function() {
       var total = 0;
       for (var i = 0; i < self.itemNumbers().length; i++)
           total += self.itemNumbers()[i].item.price;
       return total;
    });    

    // Operations
    self.addItem = function() {
        self.itemNumbers.push(new ItemEntry(self.newItem, "$20.00"));
    }
    self.removeItem = function(item) { self.itemNumbers.remove(item) }
}

ko.applyBindings(new EntryViewModel());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few updates that you would potentially want to make:

- ItemEntry accepts a `Price` argument, while you are dealing with `price` in the constructor
- Your item/price are not observables in ItemEntry, so your `formattedPrice` would not need to be a computed, it can just be a normal function (unless you choose to make them observable, like if you made a full editor
- The `formattedPrice` function is trying to read `item.price()`. Price was a separate argument and `item` is really just the name of the item.
- In `formattedPrice` you may want to consider parsing the value to a number
- when you call `addItem` the first argument will be the data at that context (which is the root view model).  So, you can either read `newItem` off of it, or just use `self.newItem()` with your current structure.
- at the end of `addItem`, you would probably want to clear `newItem`, so the input box is ready for the next entry.
- your `totalCost` computed is reading `item().price` and just needs to do `item.price`.

Here is an updated fiddle with many of these changes: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/8cDUn/

If you want to make an editor for these items, then you would likely want to make the `ItemEntry` members observable.